# Unable to install Galactic due to umet dependencies

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am currently running Ubuntu 20.
However, when I was following the steps  to install Ros2, I encounter a stranger error.
Does anyone know how to resolve the following error?

```
shouyu@shouyu-Nitro-AN515-55:~$ sudo apt install ros-galactic-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-galactic-desktop : Depends: ros-galactic-pcl-conversions but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-galactic-rqt-common-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-galactic-rviz-default-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-galactic-rviz2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411947/unable-to-install-galactic-due-to-umet-dependencies/) by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2023-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try to `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-pcl-conversions ros-galactic-rqt-common-plugins ros-galactic-rviz-default-plugins ros-galactic-rviz2`?

It should give you more information about what is missing currently in your setup. Please share it with us.

Did you use `rosdep init` and `rosdep update` in your ROS2 workspace?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on 2023-01-31**:
Hello, thank you for taking time to answer the question.

So before I saw this answer, I did the hard way, which is to reimage my Linux, and reinstalled ROS2 on the new system.

Thank you very much for your time!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-02-01**:
@sdu568 Well, I'd be lying if I said I hadn't done the same myself a few times, haha!